# How to properly handle switching of fragments in bottom navigation view

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I created a bottom navigation view using the Android sample activity, but from the looks of things I don't think it's properly implemented as i've noticed 2 things

1. The fragment recreates each time you switch between fragments
2. Sometimes when you switch fragments too fast thee app crashes with this error;

   `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment TransactionsFragment{6b18628} (462273e7-ed16-4e50-93f2-935432434a9b)} has not been attached yet.`

My question here is there a way to prevent the fragment recreation each time?

And how can I handle that error in 2?

**MainACtivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static BottomNavigationView navView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        addBadgeView();
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_transactions, R.id.navigation_wallets, R.id.navigation_account)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
//        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    }

    private void addBadgeView() {
        navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navView.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.navigation_transactions); // Show badge
    }

}
```

**Fragment.java** (this is how I instantiate a fragment in oncreate)

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private static String TAG = HomeFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
          final View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        return root;
    }
```

Comment: If you use navigation component fragment will be recreate. No way to deal with that

Comment: alright I see, i'd try going with another method then, thank you

Comment: what do you recommend the best way is?

Comment: Handle fragment manager and fragment transaction by self but it so difficult. Maybe I can give you example. Annother way you can using share view model and continue using navigation component. Keep data when fragment recreate and you dont need call API again.

Comment: please i would appreciate an example

Comment: Haha ok but now is weekend. It's time for rest haha

Comment: okay, on monday then, thank you

Comment: @CôngHải hello, could you render any assistance with this

Comment: do you still want use navigation or not? base on the requirement I can give you example

Comment: @CôngHải i still want to use navigation please